# How to navigate to td based on certain a tag inside it in selenium

Tags: selenium

I have an html table with some  and  tags,

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>first_row</td>
  <td>
   <a href = "some text1"> </td>
  <td>
   <a href = "some text2"> </td>
  <td>
   <a href = "some text3"> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>second_row</td>
  <td>
   <a href = "some text1"> </td>
  <td>
   <a href = "some text2"> </td>
  <td>
   <a href = "some text3"> </td>
 </tr>
```

From tr tag, I want xpath to td tag whose anchor tag href contains "some partial text match"
Until now I was using something like tr/td[3]/a but now I don't want to hard code the td index.
I want to search td based on anchor tag href.

I have tried,

```
findElement(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='second_row']/parent::tr/*[contains(text(),'some_text2')]").click()
```

Working code is,

```
findElement(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='second_row']/parent::tr/td[3]/a").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
findElement(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='second_row']/parent::tr//a[contains(@href,'some_text2')]").click()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).